# Help with 3.5" display

Tags: gpio, hdmi, display, retropie

i have a 3.5" display that works perfectly but i don't know how to connect it to GPIO. I'm searching on internet, but i am finding nothing.
how can i make it work? I need to force video output to GPIO.
my display:
https://www.amazon.it/Raspberry-Tablet-Pollici-Resolution-Interface/dp/B01CNLYL1C/ref=sr_1_5?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1505164535&sr=1-5&keywords=display+raspberry

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure the screen. From [here](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)):

dowload the driver:

```
wget http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/4/4b/LCD-show-161112.tar.gz
```

unzip it:

```
tar xvf LCD-show-*.tar.gz
cd LCD-show/
```

Install the driver and it toggles the mode to LCD display: Note: Net work connection is required while installing driver to your Pi, or else the touch won't work properly.

```
chmod +x LCD35-show
./LCD35-show
```

Note: this LCD won't work after apt-get upgrade, in such cases, please edit the config.txt file in the SD card and remove this statement: dtoverlay=ads7846

```
After system rebooting, the RPi LCD is ready to use.
```

There is more info in the link provided. You should check it to see the options.